# I created a VBA excel macro for finding duplicate values, how can I improve my code?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

***EDIT*** Thanks for the insights everyone!

**Hello** people (or should I say "World" rather ?! ^^) , it's my firs time posting here since I've just started doing some code, mostly C and VBA for Excel! I've got a mathematicians background but I'd like to delve into the coding world! I hope I won't tire you too much with this one !

At the moment I'm trying to make a VBA macro to find all the duplicate values in a range names and output them on another range of cells **but only one time each**. IE if my list is "John, John, Nick, John, George" the output I want is only John, instead of highlighting the name "John" three times.

**Below lies my code**, I thought of creating ***two separate collections***. The first one contains all the duplicate values from iterating through the range of names, and the second one, only contains each duplicate name once.Then I just output the second collection's items with a **For loop**.

I'm trying to read as much documentation I can about available methods and whatnot but I can say for sure, there's a long road ahead.

***Basically*** I'd like your input and thoughts on my code. How many points does my code get, functionally and visually. Could I have done something differently? Could I have dome something better? At this point I should mention, I'm only interested in code, and not Excel functions in general. This is purely just to practice some VBA code! Thank you for your time!

```
  Option Explicit

Sub FindUniqueDuplicates()

     Dim vRange1 As Variant, vRange2 As Range, vRange3 As Range  '''''''''''''''''''''''''
     Dim vCell1 As Range, vCell2 As Range, vCell3 As Range       '''''  Declarations '''''
     Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer                '''''''''''''''''''''''''
     Dim vBool1 As Boolean, vBool2 As Boolean
     Dim vColl As Collection, vColl2 As Collection

     Set vRange1 = Range(Range("A1").End(xlUp), Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0))
     Set vColl = New Collection
     'Debug.Print vColl.Count
     For Each vCell1 In vRange1
          vCell1.Activate
          Set vRange2 = Range(vCell1.Offset(1, 0), Range("A1").End(xlDown))

          For Each vCell2 In vRange2
               vCell2.Activate
               'Debug.Print vCell1.Value, vCell2.Value
               If vCell1.Value = vCell2.Value Then
                    vColl.Add vCell1.Value
               End If
          Next
          'Debug.Print
     Next
     'Debug.Print 'break point

     Set vColl2 = New Collection
     vColl2.Add vColl.Item(1)                          ''''' set vColl2 as new collection to hold
     k = 1                                             ''''' only the unique values from the range


     For i = 1 To vColl.Count
          vBool1 = False
          For k = 1 To vColl2.Count
          Debug.Print vColl2.Item(k), vColl.Item(i)
               If vColl.Item(i) = vColl2.Item(k) Then
                    vBool1 = True                      ''''' Condition to check if vColl2 holds
                    Exit For                           ''''' the value already
               End If
          Next
          If vBool1 = False Then                       ''''' Append the unique value to vColl2
               vColl2.Add vColl.Item(i)
          End If
     Next

     'Debug.Print 'break point

     Range("B1").Select
     ActiveCell.Value = "These are the duplicate names"
     For k = 1 To vColl2.Count
          Cells(k + 1, 2).Value = vColl2.Item(k)
     Next
     Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Collections have the drawback that one has to loop through to find something. An alternative is to write a `Contains`method (see [here](http://codevba.com/help/collection.htm)) which uses `on error` to detect the absence of the indexed item. You might want to have a look at [Dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) objects. They can tell the presence or absence of a key directly without enumeration. Apart from that, your question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Try `Set vRange1 = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`. You should fully qualify your ranges (include worksheet at least)... Depending how much data you are looping this over, might prove very slow... You should take the data in an array first, and you can do that without looping (`arr = range`), and that's the same for putting it back to the sheet (`range = arr`). Basically, the less you interact with the sheet, the faster your code will be.

Comment: And kudos for including `Option Explicit`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of main points:

- There is more than one way to detect duplicates. Building two Collections (or Dictionaries) to trck result is a good one, but it can be done in a single loop.
- A `Dictionary` offers three important benefits here: it offers `.Exists` which makes adding unique items easy, it offers the `.Items` property that makes placing the result on the sheet easy, and in this case it's faster.

  - You will need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`, or convert to `Late Binding` (Note: for Windows only, Mac doesn't have this option)

Other points:

- Variable naming: no need for the prefix, it adds nothing useful
- Use `Long` rather than `Integer`
- Don't use `Select`, create objects to refer to the sheet and range instead
- Copy the data range to a `Variant Array` and loop that.  Much faster than looping a range
- Place the whole result range on the sheet in one go, again much faster
- Clear any old data from the sheet before returning results
- `.End(xlUp)` is usually prefered. It ensures that blanks in the data range don't cut the range short - YMMV

Something like this

```
Function UniqueDuplicates(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim Dat As Variant
    Dim Dict As Dictionary, Dict2 As Dictionary
    Dim rw As Long

    ' Copy to Variant Array for speed
    Dat = rng.Value2
    Set Dict = New Dictionary
    Set Dict2 = New Dictionary
    For rw = 1 To UBound(Dat, 1)
        If Dict.Exists(Dat(rw, 1)) Then
            ' Its already noted, check if its already listed as a dup
            If Not Dict2.Exists(Dat(rw, 1)) Then Dict2.Add Dat(rw, 1), 1
        Else
            ' Add to already noted values
            Dict.Add Dat(rw, 1), 1
        End If
    Next
    ' return Unique set of Duplicates
    If Dict2.Count > 0 Then
        UniqueDuplicates = Application.Transpose(Dict2.Keys)
    End If
End Function
```

Use it like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim res As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    res = UniqueDuplicates(rng)
    With rng.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)
        .ClearContents
        .Resize(UBound(res), 1) = res
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1, but personally I prefer to use collections if it's only about checking if the current item is a duplicate of an existing item because they are faster.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk thanks for the comment, it prompted me to have a look at performance.  My original answer using `CountIfs` was a lot slower than the double Dictionary or Collection appraoch.  But the Dictionary is actually quite a bit faster than Collections in this case (but I agree, in general Collections are often faster than Dictionaries)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks for taking some time with your answer, it really gave me another perspective on the matter. i wasn't fully aware of the .valu2 property